# Using "Field Type" Variable (Derived from Field Iterator) as inline-variable (with a prefix string) in field calculator

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator, modelbuilder, expression, iterator

I am trying to calculate the per person load discharge by multiplying "Service Population" of various years to a constant Double type variable fed as a parameter called "Loading".

The  Service population is calculated by multiplying percent coverage to the various year populations. The percent coverage is available in the input table/ feature class "Service  Area Coverage Feature Class" as a field  called "Coverage", also made  variable called "Coverage Field", this field can also be selected in the model through Get Field Values.

[image: Input Table/ Feature Class]

[image: Model Snapshot]

[image: Model Snapshot 2]

The population of various years is available in the input feature class with field  names starting with the "p_".
The user gets to choose the population fields through the "Field Iterator",  the Values  from this iterator are named as "Current Field" Variable, which shall be later used to add multiple fields and calulation in the added fields within the same input FC. By default I  have selected two fieldnames only "p_2040",and "p_2055".

The add multiple fields then adds, two new fields to the input FC, having names "Current Field" prefixed with Service_, and MLD_ respectively, for each field iterations. The new field names are expected to look like : Service_p_2040,  MLD_p_2040, Service_p_2055,  MLD_p_2055.

[image: Add Multiple Fields]

Then, Calculate field is used in these newely created fields,first on Service_p_2040, then MLD_p_2040.
Service_p_2040 is Service population for year 2040, calculated by multiplying Coverage field with the p_2040 field. (i.e., "%Coverage Field%" * "%Current Field%") This also uses a variable "Current Pop Field" which is the name  of the  field itself "Service_%Current Field%" so it can be used in the next calculation.

[image: Population Field Calculator Expression used]

[image: Error While Running Calculate Service Population]

Then, MLD_p_2040 is calculated by multiplying Loading with newly created Service_p_2040 field,and dividing by 10^6.(i.e., "%Current Pop Field%" * %Loading% / math.pow(10,6))

[image: Load Field Calculator Expression used]

While the add multiple fields is successful,but I get error during the field calculation (expression and error given in screenshot)
I can't  figure out what I am  doing wrong, maybe the inline variable substitution for the field prefixed with a string has not be put in right syntax.